# Multiple ListView Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to have 6 `ListView` in one activity. No two of them visible at the same time.
On selection of 1st list i want to make certain `View` to be visible. So how do i come to know which `ListView` was Visible so that i can process it. Any Way of knowing it ?

Comment: Can you explain better ?

Comment: If you want to hide some of your lists I would say use an ExpandableListView

Comment: certain view to be visible or particular listview to be visible?

Comment: I want to use `ListView` instead of `Spinner`. I can have multiple `spinners` in an `Activity`.Now since Spinner are pop-up and doesn't look good and since i am customising everything i dont want to use `Spinner`. So in Spinner i can get which spinner is selected. So in similar way I want to know which ListView is visible

Comment: Sorry for bad english hope u people understand it

Comment: And to make it more clear. None of the ListView is Visible when Activity Starts.Its there in a layout which is invisible

Answer (score 0):

```
mListview.isShown();
```

that will return a boolean y/n if the view visibility is set to View.VISIBLE